# elegant way of halting consumption of rabbitmq in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

What is the elegant way of halting consumption of messages when an exception happens in the consumer or listener,so the messages can be re-queued. The listener process is consuming messages from the queue and calling a different API. Now if the API is not available, we don't want to consume messages from the queue. Is there any way to stop consuming messages from the queue for a finite time and come back up again when the API is available.

any sample code snippet of how it can be done also will help.

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this, it's generally best to show a snippet of your configuration so we can answer appropriately, depending on how you are using the framework.

You can simply call `stop()` (and `start()`) on the listener container bean.

If you are using `@RabbitListener`, the containers are not beans, but are available via the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

Calling `stop()` on the registry stops all the containers.

Or, you can call `registry.getListenerContainer(id).stop()`, where `id` is the value of the `@RabbitListener` 's `id` property.

Comment: Thank you Gary. We will try out this.